# Is a non-restrictive relative clause a subordinate clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

> a. The mayor, **who lives in this house**, has not been seen for days.

> This is a non-restrictive relative clause, since it provides supplementary information about *the mayor*, but is not essential to the sentence – if the clause were omitted, it would still be known which mayor is meant. If the bold part is deleted the remaining part provides the sense. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Restrictive_and_non-restrictive))

Is a non-restrictive relative clause such as this a subordinate clause?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110353/discussion-on-question-by-listeneva-is-a-non-restrictive-relative-clause-a-subor).

Answer (score 1):

"A nonessential (nonrestrictive) clause *is a subordinate clause* that is not essential to the meaning of the sentence but merely adds an idea to the sentence." [1]

Thus, by definition, a nonrestrictive clause is also a subordinate clause.

[1]: Warriner's *English Grammar and Composition*, Complete Course

Comment: Yes, but non-restrictive relative clauses are special in that unlike restrictive relatives they don't modify an antecedent and combine with it to form a larger nominal. They are inherently non-defining, by virtue of not being integrated into the syntactic structure.